# Outbound IP addresses for Azure functions

Tags: azure, function, api, ip, cloud

I'm running an azure function which gets data from an API and stores it in a blob. Everything worked fine and stopped working out of nowhere. We then got in contact with our provider and they told us they made some changes in their API. After we made the necessary changes in our code,started getting an IP denied error from their part. I then searched and found the possible outbound IP addresses for the Azure Function. They whitelisted the whole list and still

1. They aren't getting any requests from those IP's,
2. We are not able to access that data for the same reason our IP is denied.

We've been running the code in a local machine and it works completely fine, but this is just a temporary fix and we want to keep everything in the cloud.

I've been stuck with this for about 3 weeks. I've looked into different solutions and I found about Azure Logic Apps and Azure Service Fabric.

Is there something missing in my Azure Function that isn't allowing me to make requests to the API? Am I using the wrong outbound IP? Also, if I use any of the other two services, will I encounter with the same problem? I did some research on them and I think they both also use multiple outbound IP addresses, so I'm worried I'll get the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using NAT gateway you can specify a static IP address for outbound traffic, your function app need to be attached on a subnet which is not available for consumption plan.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is where you should be getting the Azure IP address ranges from](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519). Azure Functions originate from the App Service Plan ranges. Note that this is updated weekly, things change, but not too often. Your provider will need to open all the relevant ranges and keep up to date with any changes. If your solution is not mission critical with a high SLA, then having your service provider open the relevant ranges and deal with failures, updating the ranges on an ad-hoc basis should be fine.

Secondly, if you have a good relationship with the provider, ask them to check the firewall, they will be able to give you an indication of the IP's getting blocked by checking the firewall logs. This will help you find the right range.

The only guaranteed way to solve this in a mission critical solution is to run your Azure Functions from an dedicated app service plan with a dedicated IP address. This is an expensive option but will be the most robust.

Additional helpful information here on how App Services works with IPs can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips).

Comment: I don't think having my provider add the IPs every x amount of time is a good idea. It's kind of a long process and we depend a lot on this API. I also looked into dedicated IP address but yeah, they're too expensive.

I feel like we're missing something that will make this work. I'm not sure how my old boss did it but somehow he got it working, but he doesn't remember how he did it (and he doesn't work with us anymore so he doesn't care that much probably).
Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: No problem David - it's a long standing issue with Functions / App Service. Maybe your provider recently added IP restrictions, hence it was working fine before.